# How do I make a chemical equation with structural formulas, arrow and catalyst on the same row?

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

[image]

I tried this:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
\includegraphics[width=0.35]{images/1,3-dimethyluracil.png} &
  \ce{HNO_3} \newline \Longrightarrow &
  \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{images/1,3-dimethyl, 5-nitrouracil.png} 
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `chemfig` package, for example as follows: The first example shows how to use pre-drawn images connecting them with an arrow with text on top, the second one uses `chemfig` to draw the molecules, as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\schemestart 
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\arrow{->[\ce{HNO3}]}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
\schemestop
\bigskip

\schemestart 
\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-=)}
\arrow{->[\ce{HNO3}]}
\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-(-N(=[:90]O)(=[:210]O))=)}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is really no need for the `chemfig` syntax to be this complicated. This: `\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-=)}` will do just fine

Comment: Not part of the question, but probably helpful to the OP, especially if you need to write chemical equations with organic compounds more often: You can add the name of the substance below the substance using `\chemname{\chemfig{*6(-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-N(-CH_3)-(=O)-=)}}{1,3-dimethyluracil}`

Comment: @MarkusG.: Thanks for pointing this out. I'm unfortunately not (yet?) that experienced using chemfig. I've updated my answer accordingly.